# Why the CSS calc() function is not working?

Tags: css, css-calc

Why this one `calc(100vw/4)` works but neither of the following do?

1. `calc(100vw/4-(10-4))`
2. `calc(100vw/4-(10px-4))`
3. `calc(100vw/4-(10px-4px))`
4. `calc(100vw/4-calc(10px-4px))`

How do I manage the expression `calc(100vw/x-(10px-x))` where `x` gets replaced in a SASS loop to work?

Comment: CSS is not a programming language, so it is not possible to do complex calculations, and it shouldnt be.

Comment: But you can see mentions of nested calcs here and there on the internet. So only one operator and no nesting?

Comment: @MatthiasS. i don't agree with you. Even if CSS is not a programming language we may sometimes consider doing some complex calculations in order to obtain some results. For sure we need first to look for simple solution but sometimes we need complex one.

Comment: @TemaniAfif If you really need to make such complex calculations, then you should use Javascript or a preprocessor, which supports this and generates pure CSS. CSS should stay as simple as possible

Comment: @MatthiasS. in this case why there is `calc` in CSS ? and why we can nest `calc` operation ? there is a reason : for example a designer with no programming knowledge like JS will be able to use these kind of stuffs in order to do what he want.

Comment: @MatthiasS guys the reason I use calc in this case is to define some defaults **while JS is not fired yet**. Further these calculations are going to be handled by JS, when it's started.

Comment: @TemaniAfif For me iIts just the seperation of concerns, CSS should not make calculations. But I know it can be useful, and it is just an opinion, its ok to disagree.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to add **spaces** between operators, it's a common mistake to forget them. We can also nest operation using `calc` as many as we want but they are equivalent to simple parentheses.

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

> **Note**: The `+` and `-` operators **must be surrounded by whitespace**. For
> instance, `calc(50% -8px)` will be parsed as a percentage followed by a
> negative length—an invalid expression—while `calc(50% - 8px)` is a
> percentage followed by a subtraction operator and a length. Likewise,
> `calc(8px + -50%)` is treated as a length followed by an addition
> operator and a negative percentage.
>
> The `*` and `/` operators **do not require whitespace**, but adding it for
> consistency is both allowed and recommended.
>
> **Note**: It is permitted to nest `calc()` functions, in which case the
> inner ones are treated as simple parentheses.

```css
.one {
  background: red;
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
  margin-top: calc(20px + calc(40px * 2)); /*Same as calc(20px + (40px * 2))*/
  height: calc(100px - 10px);
  padding: calc(5% + 10px) calc(5% - 5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="one">

</div>
```

[image]

---

Same logic when dealing with `max()`,`min()` and `clamp()` since they accept the same argument as `calc()`

Related: [Why doesn't min() (or max()) work with unitless 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62520998/8620333)

Comment: Do you know if all browsers support `calc()` nesting?

Comment: @NicolasHoizey I would say yes but you may find some particular cases .. you may refer to this link https://caniuse.com/#search=calc .. the "known issues" section

Comment: I didn't find any mention of nesting in CanIUse, that's why I asked there… ;-)

Comment: @NicolasHoizey that's why it's a *yes* unless you find something that is not working or you face a particular case ;)

Comment: @NicolasHoizey I found a not working case of nested calc . (nesging calc inside of max)