# What is the correct way to specify a padding of 0px in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have seen two notations:

padding: 0px

and just

padding: 0

I would like to know which is the correct way or syntactically correct way.

I have seen both ways in different places:

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['property: 0' or 'property: 0px' in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318471/property-0-or-property-0px-in-css)

Comment: always use `0px` and you will thank me one day (related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62520998/8620333)

Answer (score 1):

Both are syntactically correct and correct in general. When you have 0 of anything, it is still 0, so in terms of value, `0` is the same as `0px` which is the same as `0[AnyMeasurementHere]`. If you wanted to update the style later, and you were using pixels, you might keep it at `0px` to remind yourself that you are using pixels on this element for its padding.