# Why is the width of this element not 0?

Tags: css, css-calc

I have a width set with a calc, and it should be returning 0 but when I look at the computed width it says 22.2333px.

```css
:root {
  --show: 1;
}

.test {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: calc(var(--show) - 1);
  opacity: calc(var(--show) - 1);
}
```

```html
<span class="test">test</span>
<span class="test2">
      test2
    </span>
```

it seems to me that the width of .test should be 0, especially as opacity is 0. If I make the value of the width property explicitly 0 it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`width` accept length or percentage values and your `calc()` will return an integer.

It may look trivial for you because the result is `0` but it's not the case for the browser. `calc(0)` is not handled the same way as `0`. The first one is invalid with `width` while the second is valid.

> A math function can be many possible types, such as `<length>`, `<number>`, etc., depending on the calculations it contains, as defined below. **It can be used anywhere a value of that type is allowed**. <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#calc-type-checking)</sup>

Add a unit to overcome this:

```css
:root {
  --show: 1;
}

.test {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: calc((var(--show) - 1)*1px);
  opacity: calc(var(--show) - 1);
}
```

```html
<span class="test">test</span>
<span class="test2">test2</span>
```

Related: [Why doesn't min() (or max()) work with unitless 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62520998/8620333)